# NaT values aren't replaced by NaNs in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace NaT values in Pandas dataframe with NaNs as follows

```
df = df.replace([pd._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType], np.nan)
```

but then I check it back

```
  print(df["col"])
  print(type(df["col"][0]))
  print(isinstance(df["col"][0], pd._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType))
```

And get

```
0         NaT
1         NaT
2         NaT
3         NaT
4         NaT
           ..
1123568   NaT
1123569   NaT
1123570   NaT
1123571   NaT
1123572   NaT
Name: col, Length: 1123573, dtype: datetime64[ns]
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType'>
True
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this doesn't work.
`df = df.replace(pd.NaT, np.NaN)`
 or
`df.replace(pd.NaT, np.NaN, inplace=True)`

This will work, but it isn't the best probably for all cases...

```
def apply_nat_replacer(x):
    x = str(x)
    if x == 'NaT':
        x = 'nat_replaced'
    else:
        x =x
    return x

df[1] = df.apply(lambda row: apply_nat_replacer(row[1]), axis=1)
```

Comment: tried, but NaT values are still present, same situation

Comment: I thought that this would work...`def apply_nat_replacer(x):
    if x == pd.NaT:
        x = 'nat_replaced'
    else:
        x =x
    return x

df[1] = df.apply(lambda row: apply_nat_replacer(row[1]), axis=1)`
I guess that the truth of x == pd.Nat is false for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

The better question is why is the dtype associated with a date/time.  Are there values in the column that are dates/times?

```
s='''value  time
     1  NaT
     2  NaT'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep='\s+', converters={'time': pd.to_datetime})
df['time'] = df['time'].fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0).seconds).replace({0: pd.np.nan})

print(df)

   value  time
0      1   NaN
1      2   NaN
```